# What's the difference between a XML preference with slash and without it?

Tags: magento2, xml, preference

Checking the Magento core I see two patterns a class with the slash in the beginning and a class without it.

[image: Magento 2 Core preference type]

What would be the difference?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is none. I used to write the fully qualified class name with the leading slash and now I do it without the leading slash. Plugins, preferences, virtual types, arguments and anything else I have worked on have had no noticeable difference.

Looking at the `phpClassName` simpleType in  `vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd` the pattern match for the start of the string is: `\\?` (Match 0 or 1 of the `\` character) so it would seem that that the expected input does not care.

The only difference there *potentially* could be is a negligible performance difference, however the effort to investigate, benchmark and identify the faster option would be better spent working on the code in your own modules.